# Visual ranking of choices in a RedCap Survey

Tags: list, ranking, redcap

We would like our repliers to a survey to rank +15 choices from 'strongest' to 'weakest'. It would be optimal if it could be a list where you could drag/drop  the different choices so that the user continuously could sort them in their preferred rank. It could just as well be using an "arrow up" and "arrow down" function. We haven't been able to find such a possible solution in RedCap and right now some sort of radio-buttons with only one answer per rating possible is out best solution, which is quite far from what we need.

Can anyone point us in a direction? Or tell if it is simply not possible?

Kindly

Thomas fra Copenhagen University Hospital, Herlev. Denmark.

We tried with radio-buttons with only one choice of a particular rating possible. But this gets really confusing, as your first rating-choice simply disappears, if you choose the same rating further down the list.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking into matrix fields in REDCap? Creating a matrix in REDCap seems to satisfy the use case of ranking 15 choices from "strongest" to "weakest," as each of the 15 options could be considered a separate question or variable that all share the same multiple choice options. Unfortunately, I don't believe REDCap has a field where you can sort choices through dragging and dropping. Let me know if this article helps:

https://www.ctsi.ufl.edu/wordpress/files/2017/06/Using-the-%E2%80%98Matrix-of-Fields%E2%80%99-Field-Type-in-REDCap-1.pdf